# Why do we allow overflow by default?

Tags: c#, integer-overflow, language-features

I had a theory that casting from `long` to `int` with a value greater than `int.MaxValue` or less than `int.MinValue` would result in an exception. The issue I *had* at the time was identifying which type of exception was going to be thrown. I naturally assumed it would be an `OverflowException` or an `InvalidCastException`, but imagine my surprise when the following snippet didn't explode at all!

```
int x = 0;
long y = int.MaxValue;
y += 3;

try {
    x = (int)y;
} catch (Exception e) {
    Console.WriteLine(e.GetType());
}
```

This instead resulted in a value equal to `int.MinValue + 2`:

```
x:            -2147483646
int.MinValue: -2147483648
```

So my curiosity has the best of me at this point, and I've done a fair amount of digging to learn that I can cause an exception to be thrown (thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40601518/extremely-large-long-type-number-becomes-negative/40601556)) by utilizing the `checked` keyword (emphasis mine):

> Overflow checking can be enabled by compiler options, environment configuration, or use of the checked keyword. The following examples ... **Both examples raise an overflow exception**.

Meaning, if I simply utilize the `checked` keyword, an `OverflowException` will be thrown (and it is):

```
try {
    x = checked((int)y);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Console.WriteLine(e.GetType());
}
```

After reading [this article on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/checked), I've learned that the default behavior is to allow the overflow to occur:

> By default, these non-constant expressions are not checked for overflow at run time either, and they do not raise overflow exceptions. The previous example displays -2,147,483,639 as the sum of two positive integers.

---

**TL/DR**: Why is the default behavior in `C#` to allow overflow to occur? Doesn't this lead to unexpected behaviors?

**Note**: I understand that the bit flips and that's what causes it to go negative; I'm just curious as to why it's allowed to flip instead of throwing an exception by default. In a nutshell, why do we have to explicitly state we want things to explode?

Comment: Because Java did.

Comment: I think it's wrong to think of a "bit flip" that makes the result negative. Instead, the byte representation of a `long` is truncated to the number of bytes for an `int`.

Comment: An integer in c# is 32 bits and you only have a int16.

Comment: @jdweng I'm not sure I follow. `int` is a 32 bit integer and `long` is 64 bits? Where did you get `Int16` from?

Comment: performance, the reason is... just like arrays don't start with 1

Comment: Questions of the ilk "what was Microsoft thinking when.." are usually off topic

Comment: @jdweng: serious? - I thought 2^16 was something like 65536 ;-)

Comment: @jdweng I know this question is closed at this point, but as an FYI (per Google, not me): `short: 16 bits [-32768 to 32767]`.

Comment: To get an overflow on a negative number you have to subtract and you are adding.

Comment: @jdweng I understand that, it sounded like you were stating that a 16 bit number is orders of magnitude larger than it really is.